# Add abstract View to layout and decide the specific class programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, radio-button

I have an application with a fragment viewpager.

Each fragment is either of type A and contains a list of 5 `CheckBoxes` or is of type B and contains 5 `Radiobuttons`.

For now, I have an `AbstractFragment` which has 2 child classes `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`, and I set either a layout with a list  or with the other.

I would like to simplify this and have only one `Fragment` class, with a list of 5 [`CompoundButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html), and set programmatically if the `CompoundButton` is a `CheckBox` or a `Radiobutton`.

Since `CompoundButton` is abstract, how can I achieve something like this ?

PS : Of course, adding the buttons programmatically is not what I want to do, since the layout is a somehow complicated and setting it would be tedious.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ComponentFragment extends Fragment {
    private ComponentFragmentMode mode = ComponentFragmentMode.CHECKBOX;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        if (mode == ComponentFragmentMode.CHECKBOX) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox_layout, container, false);
        } else {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.radiobutton_layout, container, false);
        }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to have a single layout and decide the class of some widgets. But your solution is still a major improvement for me, thanks !